# subfig package in nature document class

Tags: subfloats

I am using subfig package inside the document class "nature". It is not working. Is there any other way to draw subfigures in this class?

```
\documentclass{nature}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfig}    
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}% 

\usepackage{tikz, wrapfig,array}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.markings, shapes.geometric, graphs, graphs.standard, quotes,shapes,chains,scopes,positioning,arrows}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[Simple order]{\begin{tikzpicture}[{<[scale=2.5,
          length=3,
          width=3]}-,grow=right,solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1,fill=black}]
   % \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]
    \node[solid node,label=left:{$\mu_1$}]{}
       child{node[solid node,label=above:{$\mu_2$}]{} child { node[solid node,label=above:{$\mu_3$}]{} child { node[solid node,label=right:{$\mu_4$}]{} }}}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}\label{Fig_Simple_Order}
}
\subfigure[Tree order]{\begin{tikzpicture}[{[scale=2.5,
          length=3,
          width=3]<}-,grow=right,level 1/.style={sibling distance=5mm},solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1,fill=black}]
   % \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]
    \node[solid node,label=left:{$\mu_1$}]{}
       child { node[solid node,label=right:{$\mu_4$}]{} }
        child { node[solid node,label=right:{$\mu_3$}]{} }
        child { node[solid node,label=right:{$\mu_2$}]{} }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}\label{Fig_Tree_Order}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Please note that the `subfig` package was superseded by the `subcaption` package

Comment: Give `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` a try. And no, I don't see that (my) `subcaption` package has superseded the `subfig` package, especially not in use cases where the `caption` package is incompatible to the document class used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems here:

1. `subfig` is loading the `caption` package which is incompatible to the `nature` document class (since `nature` re-defines `\caption` on its own). This can be prevented by adding the option `caption=false` to `subfig`.
2. The command `subfig` offers is called `\subfloat` (and not `\subfigure`).
3. `\subfloat` expects `\@captype` to be defined. But the `nature` document class re-defines `figure` without setting `\@captype` in its own definition. So we need to set `\@captype` for ourself.

```
\documentclass{nature}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}% 

% Offer \setcaptiontype to set \@captype - This is needed by \subfloat
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setcaptiontype[1]{\edef\@captype{#1}\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz, wrapfig,array}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.markings, shapes.geometric, graphs, graphs.standard, quotes,shapes,chains,scopes,positioning,arrows}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\setcaptiontype{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Simple order]{\begin{tikzpicture}[{
```

Comment: Thank you Axel. It is working but there is one problem. The caption does not stick to the graph position. It is appearing on the last page. Please help if possible.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash I'm not familiar with the requirements of Nature, but this is written in nature.cls: "Nature wants things in the order: title, ...figure legends" and "Redefine the figure and table environments. The new figure environment defers printing of all figure captions until the end of the document and prints them in sans serif font. The \includegraphics command is ignored since Nature wants figures as separate files." So it seems to me that this is intentional and the figure content (i.e. the sub-figures) must be delivered as separate file.